# Salt sls file format with jinja if sentense

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack, esxi

I am trying to learn salt, and I want to use to to se advanced settings on ESXi hosts using the "salt-ext-modules-vmware" modules.

I have the following sls file:

```
{% for host in salt['vmware_esxi.list_hosts']() %}
        {% if salt['vmware_esxi.get_advanced_config']('host_name={{ host }}','config_name=Net.BlockGuestBPDU' == 0) %}
        set_advanced_option_{{host}}:
          module.run:
            - name: vmware_esxi.set_advanced_config
            - host_name: {{ host }}
            - config_name: Net.BlockGuestBPDU
            - config_value: 1
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I run the command to get a setting if work like it should.

Command:
salt 'proxy-minion' vmware_esxi.get_advanced_config host_name=hostname.domain.com config_name=Net.BlockGuestBPDU

And if I skip the if part of the sls file it also works, but it will always set the values even when they are already set, so I decided to implement a if sentence to only set the value if it is not already correct.

But when I run the command to check the values I get an error, that I cannot figure out how to get rid of. Any help will be appreciated.

Command:
salt 'proxy-minion' state.apply

Error:

```
proxy-minion:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:all_vmhosts_advanced_settings' failed: Problem running salt function in Jinja template: Datacenter 'host_name={{ host }}' was not found; line 2

---
{% for host in salt['vmware_esxi.list_hosts']() %}
        {% if salt['vmware_esxi.get_advanced_config']('host_name={{ host }}','config_name=Net.BlockGuestBPDU' == 0) %}    <======================
        set_advanced_option_{{host}}:
          module.run:
            - name: vmware_esxi.set_advanced_config
            - host_name: {{ host }}
            - config_name: Net.BlockGuestBPDU
[...]
---
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how this works.

Here is the solution to anyone with the same problem.

Turns out that there are functions and there are state modules.

State modules will only change values if they differ from the requested setting, where as functions will just run no matter what.

Here is the state file using a state module instead of a function:

```
{% for host in salt['vmware_esxi.list_hosts']() %}
set_advanced_config_{{host}}:
  vmware_esxi.advanced_config:
    - host_name: {{host}}
    - name: Net.BlockGuestBPDU
    - value: 1
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, that's an even better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` expressions do not work when you're already in a Jinja context.
Use the variable directly.

Argument keywords are not string values.

You want the test to operate on the function result, not one of its arguments.

```py
{% if salt["vmware_esxi.get_advanced_config"](host_name=host, config_name="Net.BlockGuestBPDU") == 0 %}
```

Alternatively, instead of using Jinja, you can use an [`unless` argument](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#unless).

```yaml
set_advanced_option_{{host}}:
  module.run:
    - vmware_esxi.set_advanced_config:
      - host_name: {{ host }}
      - config_name: Net.BlockGuestBPDU
    - unless:
      - fun: vmware_esxi.get_advanced_config
        host_name: {{ host }}
        config_name: Net.BlockGuestBPDU
```

Comment: Hi,

I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately I cannot make it work. It seems that the state files can be written in a million ways, but I am not able to guess any of them :)

If I use the approach with the **unless** I have two problems.

Comment: 1) I cannot get the semantics right. When I re-write the state file like you mention. salt thinks that the *set_advanced_option_hostname* is the function name for some reason. and Gives this error:

```
          ID: set_advanced_config_host01.domain.com
    Function: module.run
      Result: False
     Comment: Module function set_advanced_config_host01.domain.com is not available
     Started: 17:55:52.642347
    Duration: 872.989 ms
     Changes:
```

Comment: 2) I do not understand how to write the unless part. I need to check for two things. First one is the returned value is different from 1, and the *vmware_esxi.set_advanced_config* function just returns the value. How can I compare it?

Comment: The I use your first answer I get an error because some hosts might be disconnected, so I might need to filter for when a host does not respond somehow.

Comment: @Brian It sounds like you are using an old Salt version. Check the documentation for `module.run` and `unless` and ideally upgrade in order to write it like this. As `0` is false and `1` is true this is the same as the `== 0` check. If you have to check whether the host exists first, then yes you need to do that too.